# How to fix lifetime error when function returns a serde Deserialize type?

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde, serde-json

I'm using serde and serde_json 1.0 to decode data from a base64 string:

```
fn from_base64_str<T: Deserialize>(string: &str) -> T {
    let slice = decode_config(string, URL_SAFE).unwrap();     
    serde_json::from_slice(&slice).unwrap()
}
```

When I compile, I got this:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:23
  |
6 | fn from_base64_str<T: Deserialize>(string: &str) -> T {
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Checking the serde doc, `Deserialize` is defined as:

```
pub trait Deserialize<'de>: Sized {
```

So I added the lifetime:

```
fn from_base64_str<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>>(string: &str) -> T {
    let slice = decode_config(string, URL_SAFE).unwrap();     
    serde_json::from_slice(&slice).unwrap()
}
```

The compiler then told me:

```
error: `slice` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:29
   |
11 |     serde_json::from_slice(&slice).unwrap()
   |                             ^^^^^ does not live long enough
12 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'de as defined on the body at 9:64...
  --> src/main.rs:9:65
   |
9  |   fn from_base64_str<'de, T: Deserialize<'de>>(string: &str) -> T {
   |  _________________________________________________________________^ starting here...
10 | |     let slice = decode_config(string, URL_SAFE).unwrap();
11 | |     serde_json::from_slice(&slice).unwrap()
12 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
```

I'm using Rust 1.18.0-nightly (452bf0852 2017-04-19). I only know the very basics of lifetimes in Rust, so I'm very confused by the `'de` in `trait Deserialize`.

How can I fix the lifetime error in such function?

Answer (score 22):

I found an answer from [Serde issue 891](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/891): I should use `DeserializeOwned` instead of `Deserialize`.

Answer (score 21):

[**This section of the Serde website covers `Deserialize` bounds in detail.**](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds)

---

There are two main ways to write `Deserialize` trait bounds, whether on an impl block or a function or anywhere else.

- **`<'de, T> where T: Deserialize<'de>`**

  This means "T can be deserialized from **some** lifetime." The caller gets to decide what lifetime that is. Typically this is used when the caller also provides the data that is being deserialized from, for example in a function like [`serde_json::from_str`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_str.html). In that case the input data must also have lifetime `'de`, for example it could be `&'de str`.
- **`<T> where T: DeserializeOwned`**

  This means "T can be deserialized from **any** lifetime." The callee gets to decide what lifetime. Usually this is because the data that is being deserialized from is going to be thrown away before the function returns, so T must not be allowed to borrow from it. For example a function that accepts base64-encoded data as input, decodes it from base64, deserializes a value of type T, then throws away the result of base64 decoding. Another common use of this bound is functions that deserialize from an IO stream, such as [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html).

  To say it more technically, the [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) trait is equivalent to the [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) `for<'de> Deserialize<'de>`. The only difference is `DeserializeOwned` is more intuitive to read. It means T owns all the data that gets deserialized.