# How to declare a generic function with a trait bound that is parameterized with a lifetime name?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

Given a generic function:

```
fn foo<T> (_x: T) {}
```

I'd like to add a `serde::Deserialize` trait bound. However the following

```
fn foo<T: serde::Deserialize> (_x: T) {}
```

results in

```
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
 --> src/lib.rs:1:11
  |
1 | fn foo<T: serde::Deserialize> (_x: T) {}
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ explicit lifetime name needed here
```

And trying it like I understand [the serde documentation regarding deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html)

```
fn foo<'de, T> where T: serde::Deserialize<'de> (_x: T) {}
```

also yields an error:

```
error: expected `(`, found `where`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:16
  |
1 | fn foo<'de, T> where T: serde::Deserialize<'de> (_x: T) {}
  |                ^^^^^ expected `(`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also [Lifetime error when creating a function that returns a value implementing serde::Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43554679/155423).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, it was just a basic error in the function syntax.

```
fn foo<'de, T>(_x: T)
where
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    // ...
}
```

is correct and works.

Comment: Or `fn foo<'de, T: serde::Deserialize<'de>> (_x: T) {}`

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, thanks. That's more concise. This might not be the ideal place here, but I also would like to say thank you on a broader scale. When I have some rust question once in a while, it's highly likely that the answer I find somewhere on the Internet was posted by you. And your work here on stackoverflow is totally amazing in any case.

Comment: I prefer the `where` clause myself, as I find it much easier to read, although the prevailing rustfmt style is to put it on multiple lines (which I've updated the answer to have). Thank you for taking the time to recognize those who have helped you; we really do appreciate it (and it's a nice change from the *other* feedback we often get ^_^)